# Calling a function using the wrong function name and without parentheses

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub TestConc()
    Dim s As String
    s = ConcatenateRange Range("A1:A4")
    MsgBox s
End Sub

Function TraceRangeString(r As Range) As String
    For Each cell In r
        TraceRangeString = TraceRangeString & cell.Address & ": " & cell & " " & Chr(13)
    Next cell
End Function
```

Why do I get a Syntax Error on `s = ConcatenateRange Range("A1:A4")`?

Comment: Did you actually mean `TraceRangeString`?

Comment: Sure =) But my mistake was, that I missed ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Sub TestConc()
    Dim s As String
    s = TraceRangeString(Range("A1:A4"))
    MsgBox s
End Sub

Function TraceRangeString(r As Range) As String
    For Each cell In r
        TraceRangeString = TraceRangeString & cell.Address & ": " & cell & " " & Chr(13)
    Next cell
End Function
```